# Orchard throws 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type Part but this dictionary requires a model of type VM

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

This is an editor for WebShop Global Settings. I needed to extend the editor with a ViewModel. It worked fine before I started but now crashes with the above error when it's invoked. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the driver:

```
public class WebShopSettingsPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<WebShopSettingsPart>
{
    private readonly ISiteService _siteService;
    private readonly IWebshopSettingsService _webshopSettings;
    protected override string Prefix { get { return "WebShopSettings"; } }

    private const string shapeName = "Parts_WebShopSettings_Edit";       
    private const string templateName = "Parts/WebShopSettings";    

    public WebShopSettingsPartDriver(IWebshopSettingsService webshopSettings, ISiteService siteService)
    {
        _webshopSettings = webshopSettings;
        _siteService = siteService;
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(WebShopSettingsPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        var settings = _siteService.GetSiteSettings().As<WebShopSettingsPart>();

        var model = new WebShopSettingsVM
        {
            WebShopSettings = settings,
            ShippingProducts = _webshopSettings.ShippingProductRecords()
        };

        return ContentShape(shapeName,
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: templateName, Model: model, Prefix: Prefix)).OnGroup("WebShop");
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Handler:

```
 public class WebShopSettingsPartHandler : ContentHandler {

    public WebShopSettingsPartHandler(IRepository<WebShopSettingsRecord> repository) {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;

        Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<WebShopSettingsPart>("Site"));
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
        OnGetContentItemMetadata<WebShopSettingsPart>((context, part) => context.Metadata.EditorGroupInfo.Add(new GroupInfo("WebShop")));
    }
}
```

And here is the first line of the View (which is in Views\EditorTemplates\Parts\WebShopSettings.cshtml):

```
@model Cascade.WebShop.ViewModels.WebShopSettingsVM
```

The Placement.ini file has the following entry:

```
<Place Parts_WebShopSettings_Edit="Content:0" />
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
public class WebShopSettingsVM
{
    public IEnumerable<ShippingProductRecord> ShippingProducts{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? ShippingProductRecordId { get; set; }

    public WebShopSettingsPart WebShopSettings { get; set; }

    // Expose all the properties of the Part directly on the VM

    [Required]
    public string AdministratorEmailAddress
    {
        get { return WebShopSettings.AdministratorEmailAddress; }
        set { WebShopSettings.AdministratorEmailAddress = value; }
    }
    [Required]
    public string ContinueShoppingUrl
    {
        get { return WebShopSettings.ContinueShoppingUrl; }
        set { WebShopSettings.ContinueShoppingUrl = value; }
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

After Bertrand's suggestion below I updated the View to:

```
@using Cascade.WebShop.ViewModels
@using Cascade.WebShop.Models
@{
    var vm = Model.Model as WebShopSettingsVM;
}
<fieldset>
    <legend>@T("Webshop")</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(x=>vm.AdministratorEmailAddress)">@T("Administrator email address")</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>vm.AdministratorEmailAddress, new { @class = "textMedium" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("AdministratorEmailAddress", "*")
...
```

Insights and suggestions greatly appreciated -- I simply can't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second copy of the driver, under a slightly different name, was present in the  'Helpers' directory. Not surprisingly, I didn't notice this. The 'Helper' driver was supplying a Part and the 'proper' driver a VM. Both were being fired and thus whether I used a VM or a Part one or other of the two drivers would throw an exception.

Deleting the spurious driver fixed the problem. Sorry Bertrand.

Answer (score 0):

The model is still the shape. Remove the directive, and access Model.Model to access your view model: Model is the shape, and Model.Model is the property named Model that is on the shape.

Just cast Model.Model to the view model's type.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I have included the VM and simplified template above for completeness. I tried your suggestion and now I get a RuntimeBinder exception: "'Cascade.WebShop.Models.WebShopSettingsPart' does not contain a definition for 'Model'". There is something very strange going on here that I cannot put my finger on.

Comment: It is like the framework is still trying to invoke the template automatically AS WELL as through the driver. Does that make sense?

Comment: And by "simplified" you mean you changed it completely. Now what gets passed into the view *is* an instance of your view model, so the @model directive on top of your view should now work just fine and you don't need to go through Model.Model. I have no idea what you mean by "invoke the template automatically as well as through the driver".

Comment: The only thing I changed was the view. I have not changed the driver so what got passed before is still being passed, and that's a WebShopSettingsVM. At the template end of things, I expect to be able to use an @model WebShopSettingsVM to access the properties. Yes? Or am I missing something?